# BIG Problems with reciving Class Object via Objectoutputstream and bytearrayobjectoutputstream ON TCP NIO

Tags: java, tcp, nio, objectoutputstream

Here is some part of my code:

This I use to receive JSONObject if it is an JSONObject, if it fails to create a JSONObject of the incoming buffer, then it is an object of class PackageFile
that contains metadata and a byte[].

```
public JSONObject receiveJSONObject(){
        JSONObject json =null;
        byte[] headerBytes=null;
        ByteBuffer buffer=null;
        try{
            buffer= ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(2000024);
            socketChannel.read(buffer);
            buffer.flip();
            headerBytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
            buffer.get(headerBytes);
            String jsonString = new String(headerBytes);
            json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            return json;
        }catch(Exception ex){
            if(ex.toString().equals("org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject")){
                System.out.println("byte[] is a FilePackage");
                getDownloadedFilePackage(buffer);
            }else{
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            json=null;
        }
        return json;
    }


private boolean getDownloadedFilePackage(ByteBuffer buffer){
        FilePackage filePackage=null;
        ByteArrayInputStream in=null;   
        ObjectInputStream obIn=null;
        try{
            if(buffer!=null){
                in = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.array()); //Fails,,see: PR1
                obIn = new ObjectInputStream(Channels.newInputStream(socketChannel));
                filePackage= (FilePackage) obIn.readObject();
                fdm.addFilePackageToDownloadingProtocol(filePackage);
                in.close();
                obIn.close();
                return true;
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

PR1: When it fails `in = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.array());`, it gives this exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.array(ByteBuffer.java:959)
    at Client.CommunicationProtocol.getDownloadedFilePackage(CommunicationProtocol.java:115)
    at Client.CommunicationProtocol.receiveJSONObject(CommunicationProtocol.java:100)
    at Client.OperationManagerNIO.run(OperationManagerNIO.java:19)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This part of the code below send the FilePackage:

```
public void sendFilePackage(FilePackage filePackage,SocketChannel channel){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos =null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos =null;
        try{
            baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
            oos.writeObject(filePackage);
            //baos.writeTo(oos);//not used
            oos.flush();
            channel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(baos.toByteArray()));
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
```

Please help me! I can receive any message with JSONObject without any problems, but the problem is when I'm trying to send a class object, it does not work! I have been on this problem for 2 days now, and I can not see straight anymore.

As I said before, the problem is receiving the `FilePackage(Class)` object, it throws an exception on the first row that handles the incoming buffer from TCP NIO socketChannel.

I have tried to:
Just send FilePackage object - didn't succeed, the problem lays there, - how to send and retrieve a class object via `Objectoutputstream` and `bytearrayoutputstream`.

Comment: You're assuming that `read()` fills the buffer. See the Javadoc. It is only obliged to transfer one byte, or zero in non-blocking mode. You're tempting fate trying to use a combination of NIO and streams. I would use streams for everything in thi case.